# 403 forbidden on POST request nginx + amazon linux 2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, http-post, amazon-linux-2

I have setup a server on AWS everything working fine, i am able to fetch data from server but unable to POST, POST data is continuously giving 403 forbidden response,

i have check nginx logs, call never even reach there, but GET request are shows up on `access.log`.

`error.log` are empty and nothing happening there.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3004";
    }
}
```

and yes there is a Load Balancer which is running on 443 port and forward to port 80 on the instance.

Comment: can you share a little bit more details about it. Is there anything (Loadbalancer...) infront of your instance? In general AWS Security Groups are not working on that level. Can you share the full NGINX Config as well? `sudo nginx -T`

Comment: i have edit my question please have a look.

Comment: Thanks still not fully clear to me: You are saying your are listing on Port443 on the same EC2 instance and then you are proxying this request to your server running on port 80 and this is proxying the request to your application listing in port 3004?? Beside from that, try to send a POST request to your app running on 127.0.0.1:3004. `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3004` send some data if needed.

Comment: if i curl from same server or from bastion server it works like charm, but from load balancer, it doesn’t.

Comment: and i am listing on port 80 on server and on port 443 on load balancer, e.g call goes to 
load-balancer:443 -> server:80 and then proxing to 3004 to my app.

Comment: Can you check to logs / config on the LB listining port 443? Looks like something is blocking your POST request on the LB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it after looking all the way arounds, there was a rule defined on Load Balancer, post call methoud be defined in lower case like `post` not `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 403 Forbidden errors from the AWS Load Balancer WAF when the body of my POST request contained "http://127.0.0.1".  When I change it to "http://localhost" instead, it doesn't fail.  That's pretty lame.